# DocuSign OAuth Callback URL Error

Tags: oauth, docusignapi

I am seeing callback URL for DocuSign Oauth gets updated after I submit my email on DocuSign login page.
This is the URL for my OAuth flow which takes user to the DocuSign (sandbox) Login page.

```
https://account-d.docusign.com/oauth/auth?response_type=code&client_id=REST-41b3bb1d-94dc-44e3-b791-4810407b961d&scope=all&redirect_uri=https://localhost&state=https://localhost2/super/fx/oauth-callback.flex?osp=29cad06bee24300015fc6c67f95808d2%26intsys%3Dfe7a908b327570000b21578fac28005b#/username
```

Notice that the callback URL has a "osp" variable but it gets stripped away after email submission.

```
https://account-d.docusign.com/username?response_type=code&client_id=REST-41b3bb1d-94dc-44e3-b791-4810407b961d&scope=all&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%2Fcb1&state=https%3A%2F%2Flocalhost2%2Fsuper%2Ffx%2Foauth-callback.flex%3Fosp#/password
```

Comment: What is your question? If you are implementing OAuth with DocuSign then you should follow the documentation on docs.docusign.com.

Comment: Hey @LarryK, I want to get some insight on why the 'osp' variable was stripped away in the URL in the process of OAuth flow and how we can prevent it. It seems to me that DocuSign encodes the URL once a user submits their email, would this issue be related to this encoding process? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Re:

> I want to get some insight on why the 'osp' variable was stripped away in the URL in the process of OAuth flow and how we can prevent it. It seems to me that DocuSign encodes the URL once a user submits their email, would this issue be related to this encoding process?

In the OP, url being sent to DocuSign's OAuth service is:

```
https://account-d.docusign.com/oauth/auth?response_type=code&client_id=REST-41b3bb1d-94dc-44e3-b791-4810407b961d&scope=all&redirect_uri=https://localhost&state=https://localhost2/super/fx/oauth-callback.flex?osp=29cad06bee24300015fc6c67f95808d2%26intsys%3Dfe7a908b327570000b21578fac28005b#/username
```

Let's pull it apart:

```
response_type=code
client_id=REST-41b3bb1d-94dc-44e3-b791-4810407b961d
scope=all
redirect_uri=https://localhost
state=https://localhost2/super/fx/oauth-callback.flex?osp=29cad06bee24300015fc6c67f95808d2%26intsys%3Dfe7a908b327570000b21578fac28005b#/username
```

So it is **not** the case that the `osp` value is being included with the redirect uri. It is being included with the `state` query parameter.

You should instead send

```
response_type=code&client_id=REST-41b3bb1d-94dc-44e3-b791-4810407b961d&scope=all&redirect_uri=https://localhost?osp=29cad06bee24300015fc6c67f95808d2%26intsys%3Dfe7a908b327570000b21578fac28005b#/username&state=1234567890
```

In addition, it is not clear to me that including two ? characters in the overall URL is supported. I'd try encoding your ?, which is the second one in the URL.